# Jquery autocomplete custom HTML results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm building a search with jQuery UI Autocomplete (http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

I am also utilizing the jQuery UI Autocomplete HTML Extension so I can style the search nicely and display icons according to the category where the search result is in.

My problem is, when I click on a result which looks like this:

```
(Category Icon) Pink Floyd - Category
```

It comes out like this in the search input field:

```
<div class="search_icons"><img src="images/ico/search_icon_rock.png" class="search_pic_radius"></div>Pink floyd<div class="autocomplete_category"> Rock</div><div class="artist_id_search">15</div><div class="artist_name_search">pink-floyd</div>
```

This is how my search.php looks like:

```
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    $return_arr = array();

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";port=8889;dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT url_name,name,category,id FROM artists WHERE name LIKE :term OR category LIKE :term LIMIT 10');
        $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            if($row['category'] == '1') { $category_icon = '<div class="search_icons"><img src="images/ico/search_icon_rock.png" class="search_pic_radius"></div>'; }
            if($row['category'] == '2') { $category_icon = '<div class="search_icons"><img src="images/ico/search_icon_pop.png" class="search_pic_radius"></div>'; }

            $return_arr[] = $category_icon . $row['name'] . '<div class="autocomplete_category"> ' . $row['category'] . '</div>'. '<div class="artist_id_search" id="artist_id_search">' . $row['id'] . '</div>'. '<div class="artist_name_search" id="artist_name_search">' . $row['url_name'] . '</div>' ;

        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is, when clicking on something on the autocomplete it should submit the form with the value from the last two div's `artist_id_search` and `artist_name_search` so on submit the next page would become `whatever.php?id=15&artist=pink-floyd`

What I have tried is to remove the unnecessary parts from the search string with the split function but then I just ended up with the `id` and the `url_name` parameters in the search field which didn't really achieve anything also it didn't really work reliably with changing icon names and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well instead of returning HTML from the PHP service you have made in JSON, you should be returning a proper JSON like in the form of

```
[
{"id":"15","name":"pink-floyd","value":"Pink Floyd"},
{...
]
```

then handle it in your javascript as:

```
$( "#your_input_id" ).autocomplete({
      source: "your_php_page.php",
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {//callback function when you select an item
        log( ui.item ?
          "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
          "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
        window.location.href = 'whatever.php?id=ui.item.id&artist=ui.item.name';
      }
    });
```

Hope you get it sorted :)

Comment: Can I pass back the JSON 2 times from the php ? Once for what's displayed in the search result and again for the values once you click on one of the search results?

Comment: Why do you unnecessarily want to pass back the same data two times, it is a performance loss and not required anyways. I guess you want to do that to apply specific styling from your custom css, but you can do that by manipulating data in Javascript and filling it in innerHTML properties of DOM elements.

Comment: You're totally right, I got it "kind of" sorted out now, building a proper JSON, however I do have one problem, how can I access the thing from the JSON on the page with the search ? In the php it now looks like this: `$return_arr[] = array('label'=>$category_icon . $row['name'] . '<div class="autocomplete_category"> ' . $row['category'] . '</div>','artist_id'=>$row['id'],'url_name'=>$row['url_name']) ;`  as you can see in JSON the values I want to access are `artist_id` and `url_name` on the search page should I not be able to access them with `ui.item.url_name` and `ui.item.artist_id` ?

Comment: Don't know why it didn't work, but it does now when accessing via `ui.item.url_name` great ! Thanks

Comment: good going @maricos, now use the browser console : console.log(ui.item) to check the data you are getting returned from the service